# How to organize widgets in Unreal Engine for multiplayer

Tags: architecture, gui, unreal, blueprints

I am a beginner UI programmer working with UMG.

My question: are there ways to organize widgets other than, you know, the master widget that holds the rest of the widgets?

WBP_Master -> (SomeWidgets) -> (SomeWidgets)

Clarification: I would like to optimize my architecture for a project with a lot of players.
Can you advise something?